# Moving an Array to a Range VARIABLE

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I am trying to find this but I can't! Is it possible to move/copy and VBA Array to a **Range *Variable***, I am not saying a Range cells, it's a Range that you declare (ex: DIM ran as Range)

I want something like this:

```
Public Function test()

Dim ran As Range
Dim myArray(4) As Integer

myArray(1) = 1
myArray(2) = 2
myArray(3) = 3
myArray(4) = 4

'If I do this, it works!
Range("A1:A4") = myArray

'But I want this and it does not work!
ran = myArray

End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is in the array?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  A Range is a worksheet object and an array is an indexed series of same-typed data values.  You can only set range object variables = worksheet range objects.

Comment: However, it is worth noting that you could have an array of range objects: `Set myArray(0) = Range("A1:A10")` and `Set myArray(1) = Range("C1:C10")`

Comment: Having no idea what myArray actually is though makes this tough to answer.

Comment: What do you actually want here? Do you want to access an array through the `Range` *interface*? E.g., `myArray.Rows(1)`?

Comment: @Braulio, both of my comments still stand

Comment: Agree with @tigeravatar. What you call a range "variable" is not actually a variable: it is a reference, which should point to a worksheet range object. Think of it as an alias of an existing range object.. It will either be empty or it will be used in place of a worksheet range. Nothing is actually stored there..

Comment: Understood now. Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: As to 2021 `Range("A1:A4") = myArray` doesn't work anymore :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the Range is declared in code, it's still a [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), not an array.  If myArray is actually a Range object (in which case you should re-think your naming conventions) you should be able to do what your example showed.

However if your variable myArray is some other type of object (like and array) you can't just set it like that, you would have to write a method that converts myArray to a range.

**EDIT:**

I'm guessing that the reason that `Range("A1:A4") = myArray` works is because the assignment operator has been overloaded to support it as short-hand for `Range("A1:A4").Value = myArray`.

A Range however is not just an array, it's a data structure specific to Ranges of a workbook

When you declare `Dim ran As Range` you haven't actually initialized your Range object yet.  I'm guessing that if you did the following it would work:

```
Dim ran As Range("A1:A4")
Dim myArray(4) As Integer

myArray(1) = 1
myArray(2) = 2
myArray(3) = 3
myArray(4) = 4

ran = myArray
```

Comment: This is correct as a range refers to a range in an office document (cells in Excel, part of a document in Word.)  In both cases it always refers to something in the document (rather than just an adhoc class/memory address.)

Comment: Also, I understand that Range is an Array but I see that the Range has some internal structure, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Braulio - yes and no (in that order). A Range is not an array, it's an object with Properties and Methods.  It might *behave* or *look* like an array in some cases: Eg you can refer to `MyRange(3)` but that's just shorthand for `myRange.Cells(3)`, and you can assign the value of a Range to be the contents of an array, but a Range is still a distinct class of object.

Comment: Two things: (1) VBA isn't smart enough to handle operator overloading; what's actually going on here is that if VBA is expecting a property or method and doesn't see one, it inserts a *default method,* in this case `.Value`. (2) VBA doesn't support initializing variables on the same line you declare them, since the declaration isn't actually code in classic VB. You need to write `Dim ran as Range` and then `Set ran = Range("A1:A4")`.

Comment: Understood now. Thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variant to a worksheet range you get a 2 dimensional array. Try this

```
Sub MoveArray()

Dim myArray

myArray = Range("A1:B3").Value

Range("A6:B8").Value = myArray


End Sub
```

Or this

```
Sub MoveArray2()

Dim myArray
Dim myArray2
Dim myRange
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

myArray = Range("A1:B3").Value

Set myRange = Range("A6:B8")
For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count
        myRange.Cells(i, j) = myArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

myArray2 = myRange

End Sub
```

In either case the variant becomes an array rather than a range object and the loops set the values of the range from the array.

Edit

As you can see from the comments in the questions/answers in this thread a range is not an array, it is a complex object that has many properties and methods. One of the properties (I think the default property) is value. This property is in fact a 2 dimensional array (or at least behaves like one) of the values of the cells in the range. As such if myArray is also a 2 dimsensional aray the code `myRange = myArray` will execute. What will happen is the value of the cells that the range refers to will be set to the values in the array. The range refers to these cells, but it is the values in the cells that change rather than the range object.

As such if if you transfer a range to a diferent set of cells the new set of cells retains it's values.

On a practical side if you want to change the values of the cells that a range referes to you can do it as shown below:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim myArray(1 To 4, 1 To 1)
Dim myRange As Range

myArray(1, 1) = 1
myArray(2, 1) = 2
myArray(3, 1) = 3
myArray(4, 1) = 4

Set myRange = Range("A1:A4")
myRange = myArray

End Sub
```

Comment: not related to the question, but also pretty neat, is that the default .Value method can even be used straight to copy data between multi-cell ranges rather than with an intermediate step like in the MoveArray example like `Range("A1:A5").Value = Range("A6:A10").Value` (though I have no idea if VBA will internally use a temporary array, in which case it doesn't save any space vs. the example - it does save typing though!)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey on the downside if you attempt to alter the cells a range refers to, but forget the set keyword it copies the values to the original range.

Comment: Understood now. Thanks a lot to everyone!